# Tangent calculation on a Sphere leaves missing faces at the South Pole

Tags: glsl, gpu

Howdy wonderful folks!

I am doing an planetary simulation of Earth from space and stuck at the normal mapping stage. I went through a bunch of tutorials on the internet and wrote the logic to calculate tangents, pass them to the vertex shader and calculate the normal in TBN space and then use the normal for calculate the lighting using the phong model. Everything seems to work correctly but at the south pole of the planet, I get missing triangles and hence black spots:

[image]
The code for calculating the geometry of the sphere goes along the lines of:

```
void Sphere::generateMesh(){

    float deltaPhi = (float)PI/stacks;
    float deltaTheta = (2 * (float)PI)/slices;

    for(float phi = 0; phi < PI ; phi += deltaPhi){
        for(float theta = 0; theta < 2*PI - 0.001; theta += deltaTheta){

            float x1 = -sinf(phi) * sinf(theta) * radius;
            float y1 = -cosf(phi) * radius;
            float z1 = -sinf(phi) * cosf(theta) * radius;

            float u1 = float( atan2(x1, z1) / (2 * PI) + 0.5 );
            float v1 = float( -asin(y1) / (float)PI + 0.5 );

            float x2 = -sinf(theta + deltaTheta) * sinf(phi) * radius;
            float y2 = -cosf(phi) * radius;
            float z2 = -sinf(phi) * cosf(theta + deltaTheta) * radius;

            float u2 = float( atan2(x2, z2) / (2 * PI) + 0.5 );
            float v2 = float( -asin(y2) / ((float)PI) + 0.5 );

            float x3 = -sinf(theta + deltaTheta) * sinf(phi + deltaPhi) * radius;
            float y3 = -cosf(phi + deltaPhi) * radius;
            float z3 = -sinf(phi + deltaPhi) * cosf(theta + deltaTheta) * radius;

            float u3 = float( atan2(x3, z3) / (2 * (float)PI) + 0.5 );
            float v3 = float( -asin(y3) / (float)PI + 0.5 );

            float x4 = -sinf(theta) * sinf(phi + deltaPhi) * radius;
            float y4 = -cosf(phi + deltaPhi) * radius;
            float z4 = -sinf(phi + deltaPhi) * cosf(theta) * radius;

            float u4 = float( atan2(x4, z4) / (2 * (float)PI) + 0.5 );
            float v4 = float( -asin(y4) / (float)PI + 0.5 );


            Vec3f p1(x1, y1, z1);
            Vec3f uv1(u1, v1, 0);
            Vec3f p2(x2, y2, z2);
            Vec3f uv2(u2, v2, 0);
            Vec3f p3(x3, y3, z3);
            Vec3f uv3(u3, v3, 0);
            Vec3f p4(x4, y4, z4);
            Vec3f uv4(u4, v4, 0);

            //addTriangle(x1, y1, z1, u1, v1,
            //  x2, y2, z2, u2, v2,
            //  x3, y3, z3, u3, v3);

            //addTriangle(x1, y1, z1, u1, v1,
            //  x3, y3, z3, u3, v3,
            //  x4, y4, z4, u4, v4); 

            addTriangle(p1, uv1, p2, uv2, p3, uv3);
            addTriangle(p1, uv1, p3, uv3, p4, uv4);
        }
    }
}
```

The addTriangle method adds the triangles to their data structures which in turn are used for passing vertices, normals, tangents and texture coordinates in to the vertex buffer objects to the shaders. The method somewhat looks like this:

```
void Object::addTriangle(Vec3f v1, Vec3f u1, Vec3f v2, Vec3f u2, Vec3f v3, Vec3f u3){
    //add triangle normally
    addTriangle(v1, v2, v3);

    //TODO integrate uv coordinates in face
    //add extra texture coordinates to the uv vector
    uv.push_back(u1);
    uv.push_back(u2);
    uv.push_back(u3);

    Vec3f e1 = v2 - v1;
    Vec3f e2 = v3 - v1;

    float deltaU1 = u2.x - u1.x;
    float deltaV1 = u2.y - u1.y;
    float deltaU2 = u3.x - u1.x;
    float deltaV2 = u3.y - u1.y;

    float f = 1.f / (deltaU1 * deltaV2 - deltaU2 * deltaV1);

    Vec3f tangent;
    tangent = f * (deltaV2 * e1 - deltaV1 * e2);

    auto tangentIter = find(tangents.begin(), tangents.end(), tangent);

    // if tangent not in the vector, then add it and set iter to the
    // vector's tail. 
    if (tangentIter == tangents.end()){
        tangents.push_back(tangent);
        tangentIter = tangents.end() - 1;
    }

    GLuint tangentIndex = tangentIter - tangents.begin();

    face* face = faces.back();
    face->t = tangentIndex;

    vector<Vec3f> triangleVertices;
    triangleVertices.push_back(v1);
    triangleVertices.push_back(v2);
    triangleVertices.push_back(v3);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < triangleVertices.size(); i++){
        Vec3f v = triangleVertices.at(i);
        if (sharedTangents.find(v) == sharedTangents.end()){
            sharedTangents.insert(pair<Vec3f, Vec3f>(v, tangent));
        }
        else{
            Vec3f& vt = sharedTangents.at(v);
            vt += tangent;
        }
    }   
}
```

While initializing the buffers, I call this method to calculate tangents for each vertex:

```
void Object::calculateVertexTangents(){
    vector<Vec3f> vertexTangentList;
    //find the mean of all the tangents which are shared by the vertex,
    //and normalize and add them to the vertex tangent vector

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < points.size(); i++){
        Vec3f vt = sharedTangents.at(points.at(i));
        vt.normalize();
        vertexTangentList.push_back(vt);
    }

    outVertexTangents = new float[faces.size() * 3 * 3];
    Vec3f vt;
    int index = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++){
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            vt = vertexTangentList.at((*faces.at(i))[j]);
            outVertexTangents[index] = vt.x;
            outVertexTangents[index + 1] = vt.y;
            outVertexTangents[index + 2] = vt.z;

            index += 3;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my vertex and fragments shader code lies here: 
Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 vPosition;
in vec2 vTexCoord;
in vec3 vNormal;
in vec3 vTangent;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

uniform vec4 lightPosition;

out vec2 texCoord;

out vec3 lightVec;
out vec3 eyeVec;
out vec3 halfVec;

out vec3 vPos;

void main(){

    mat4 modelView = view * model;
    mat4 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(modelView));

    vec3 n = normalize ( ( normalMatrix * vec4( vNormal, 0.0 ) ).xyz );
    vec3 t = normalize ( ( normalMatrix * vec4( vTangent, 0.0 ) ).xyz );
    vec3 b = cross (n, t);

    vec4 vertexInEye = modelView * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
    vPos = vertexInEye.xyz;

    vec3 lightDir = normalize( lightPosition.xyz - vertexInEye.xyz );
    vec3 temp;
    temp.x = dot (lightDir, t);
    temp.y = dot (lightDir, b);
    temp.z = dot (lightDir, n);
    lightVec = normalize(temp);

    temp.x = dot (vertexInEye.xyz, t);
    temp.y = dot (vertexInEye.xyz, b);
    temp.z = dot (vertexInEye.xyz, n);

    eyeVec = normalize(temp);

    vertexInEye = normalize(vertexInEye);
    vec3 halfVector = normalize(vertexInEye.xyz + lightDir);
    temp.x = dot (halfVector, t);
    temp.y = dot (halfVector, b);
    temp.z = dot (halfVector, n);

    halfVec = temp ; 

    texCoord = vTexCoord;

    gl_Position = projection * modelView * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 400 core

uniform vec4 lightColor;
uniform vec4 diffuseColor;
uniform sampler2D mySampler;
uniform sampler2D night;
uniform sampler2D clouds;
uniform sampler2D specMap;
uniform sampler2D bumpMap;

in vec3 vPos;

in vec3 lightVec;
in vec3 eyeVec;
in vec3 halfVec;

in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 frag_color;    

void main(){

    vec3 normal = 2.0 * texture(bumpMap, texCoord).rgb - 1.0;
    //normal.z = 1 - normal.x * normal.x - normal.y * normal.y;
    normal = normalize ( normal );

    vec4 spec = vec4(1.0, 0.941, 0.898, 1.0);
    vec4 specMapColor = texture2D(specMap, texCoord);

    vec3 L = lightVec;
    vec3 N = normal;
    vec3 Emissive = normalize(-vPos);
    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);
    float dotProd = max(dot(R, Emissive), 0.0);
    vec4 specColor = spec * pow(dotProd,6.0) * 0.6;
    float diffuse = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);

    vec2 cloud_color            =   texture2D( clouds, texCoord).rg;
    vec3 day_color              =   (texture2D( mySampler, texCoord ).rgb * diffuse + specColor.rgb * specMapColor.g) * (1 - cloud_color.r) + cloud_color.r * diffuse;
    vec3 night_color            =   texture2D( night, texCoord ).rgb * (1 - cloud_color.r) * 0.5;

    vec3 color = day_color;
    if(dot(N, L) < 0.1)
        color = mix(night_color, day_color, (diffuse + 0.1) * 5.0);
    frag_color = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

I would very much appreciate if someone would be able to point out what I'm doing wrong in the calculation of the tangents? If this information helps, when I just render the sphere with vertex normals and phong shading, I get a perfect looking planet.

---

Edit: 
Here's a screenshot when I'm just using texture shading and not using tangent space normal mapping:

[image]

Comment: It looks good also if you set only texture shading?

Comment: I think so, yes. I can post a screenshot in some time for the texture shading from the same angle.

Comment: The problem occurs even in the north pole?

Comment: No, the north pole is pretty much well shaded. Only in the south pole. :(

Comment: I just updated my post with an image which just uses texture shading. I apologize it took this long for me to upload the screenshot...